# keep "MariaDB Database Server" alive

Tags: centos, mariadb, centos7

today MariaDB Database Server randomly stopped which caused downtime on my website
is there a way to auto start MariaDB Database Server if it randomly stopped?
I had to login to webmin manually start the server.
am running a centos 7 with virtualmin
really appreciate the help.
thanks

Comment: Install and use supervisor?

Comment: Normally this is something systemd should do, but mysql stopping is not really normal in any way... I would investigate why it's stopping at all. I've never seen this in ~15 years and would prioritize investigating the problem instead of restarting mariadb.

Comment: Second what @Evert says; databases should not randomly stop. They’re complex stateful applications - unsafe shutdown can lead to data loss. Investigate the cause and treat it, not the symptoms - otherwise there is much sadness in your future…